# Client Side Speech.Synthesis .Net

Tags: .net, speech, speech-synthesis

I have developed a website using .Net and I am trying to utilize the System.Speech.Synthesis. When I develop it on the server side there is sound, but when I test on client side there is no sound. I understand by default the server doesn't have access to client's peripherals and tried to utilize different methods to play audio using the client side speakers. 
Here is some code I tried to use

```
   Dim streamAudio As New MemoryStream()
   Dim builder As PromptBuilder = New PromptBuilder()
   sounds.SelectVoice("Microsoft Anna")
   sounds.Rate = 0.1
   sounds.Volume = 100
   sounds.SetOutputToWaveFile("c:\test\sample.wav")
   builder.AppendText("Now Calling Number ")
   builder.AppendText("")
   builder.AppendText("Please proceed to Financial aid office")
   sounds.SpeakAsync(builder)
   Dim player As Media.SoundPlayer = New Media.SoundPlayer("c:\test\sample.wav")
   player.Play()
   Thread.Sleep(100)
```

Here is another example

```
 sounds.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice()
 sounds.SelectVoice("Microsoft Hazel Desktop")
 sounds.Rate = 0.1
 sounds.Speak("Now Calling Number " + NameLabel.Text)
 sounds.Speak("")
 sounds.Speak("Please proceed to Financial aid office")
 Thread.Sleep(100)
```

Will I need to call the sound utilizing javascript or clientside scripting or is there a simpler method to do so?

Comment: There is no "by default". The server cannot access the client's peripherals, period. Forget about that SoundPlayer, try and use that generated wav file (in some web-accessible location) from the client-side.

Comment: I used  html5 audio that will play the audio now have to find a way to verify the file exist and update the wav file when the page refreshes